# Rails exception handeling in custom module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a module in a lib/assets file as follows:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'cgi'
require 'json'

 module FetchRec
  rate.sample(5).each do |result|
    begin
      url = URI.parse("http://www.url.com/dprc=Y&item_id=#{result["item"]}")
     rescue
        next 
      end
     r = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body)
  end
```

When I start my server I get an exception: Syntax Error -- "Invalid next"

How can I handle exceptions in this module, so that if a url is not valid, the json parse script will skip to the next url, and parse that?

Comment: Is there a reason this code isn't inside a method rather than at the top level inside a module? Do you really want it to run as soon as the server loads?

Comment: Yeah, I have a lot of other methods that run within this module that I would ideally like to run as the server loads. Is it extremely costly to have it set up as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the begin rescue block and replace with

```
url = URI.parse("http://www.url.com/dprc=Y&item_id=#{result["item"]}") rescue nil
next if url.nil?
```

Comment: my bad. my first look prompted me that it was bad syntax which is the cause of the error but it doesn't look like it.